# Comment dire « I couldn't help but… » ?

Tags: traduction, expressions, anglais

Par exemple, si j'écoutais une conversation parmi des étrangers et que je voulais participer, je dirais en anglais « I couldn't help but notice that you're talking about… » Comment est-ce que je dirais ça en français?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Vous diriez "Je n'ai pas pu m’empêcher d'entendre (/d'écouter) ce /dont vous parliez/que vous disiez/ de quoi vous discutiez..."